# How explain this step in application of binomial expansion for commutative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to show that for two commuting matrices

$$
e^{\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}} = e^{\mathbf{A}}e^{\mathbf{B}} \Leftarrow [\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}] = 0
$$

Using the definition of the matrix exponential

$$
e^{\mathbf{A}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathbf{A}^n}{n!}
$$

I am able to get

$$
e^{\mathbf{A}}e^{\mathbf{B}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{k!n!} \mathbf{A}^{n}\mathbf{B}^{k}
$$

The binomial expansion for commutative matrices is

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{p!}{i!(p-i)!} \mathbf{A}^{p}\mathbf{B}^{p-i} = (\mathbf{A+B})^p
$$

I have been staring at the last two equations for hours now. I clearly see the similarity between the expressions, but I cannot see how I can change the summation indexes correctly so that I can make the substitution into equation 3.

### Solution using the Cauchy product formula

Starting over, and using the relation from Omnomnomnom's answer, we get that

$$
\begin{align}
e^{\mathbf{A}}e^{\mathbf{B}} &= \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!}\mathbf{A}^j \right)\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\mathbf{B}^k \right) \\ 
&=  \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j!k!} \mathbf{A}^j\mathbf{B}^k \\ 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{n} \frac{1}{m!(n-m)!}\mathbf{A}^n\mathbf{B}^{n-m} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{m=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}\mathbf{A}^n\mathbf{B}^{n-m} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})^n \\
&= e^{\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Note that this is exactly the same as proving $e^{x+y} = e^xe^y$ in the scalar case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** With the [Cauchy product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), we have
$$
\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}A^j\right)\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!} B^k\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^n \frac {1}{m!(n-m)!} A^mB^{n-m}.
$$

Comment: It is not obvious to me how I construct the Cauchy product formula that you quoted based on the information on the Wikipedia page. Could you elaborate on how you arrived at the right-hand side of your expression based on the Cauchy product definition?

Comment: @Yoda I simply took $\frac 1{i!}A^i$ as my $a_i$ and $\frac 1{j!} B^j$ as my $b_j$

Comment: @Yoda as for where the formula comes from, it's a bit more natural if you consider the product $e^{At}e^{Bt}$ instead (where $t$ is a real number).  If we group together the powers of $t$, then each coefficient is one of the $c_k$ coefficients.

Comment: Ah, the definition makes sense once I actually write down the definition and substitute. I just had to do it properly, and not merely stare at it.

Comment: I know that feeling. Glad it worked out